# Linux: Interpreted-on-read (ala php) for local files

Tags: linux, bash, php

So the specific problem is that I want a file on my system to link to a http url, but fallback to a local version if there's no connection. The catch is that the program reading this file will be expecting css and so won't, by default, execute any access/fallback script I put in the file.

This got me thinking more generally:
When you access a php file on a webserver, before you read the file contents, the php script is interpreted. As far as any program accessing the file is concerned, the contents **are** the output (I know this only works because you are accessing it over http).

Does anyone know of an equivalent for local files?
I'm aware that I could just setup apache and use a local http request to get exactly this behaviour from php, but I was interested to know if it was possible without that.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 in case that makes a diference

Comment: I don't think something like this exists, but I like your question!

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

In general the `/proc` filesystem works in a similar way, I think. Follow [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/c708.html).

<strike>Or create your own [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) which will work in user space.</strike>

Edit
There is a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) that seems to do just that: [ScriptFS](https://github.com/frodonh/scriptfs). Its README says:

> ScriptFS is a new file system which merely replicates a local file system, but replaces all files detected as "scripts" by the result of their execution.
>
> Any script is supported. In a usual way of working, ScriptFS reads on its command line the name of two programs : one that is the script interpretor, and the other one a lightweight program that tells fast if a file on the disk is a script that can be read by the first program.

I guess if you build these two programs right, they will be able to use shebangs.

Note: I have never used ScriptFS (yet).