# Making a 'special file' like /dev/null on Linux

Tags: linux, unix, streaming

Is there any way one could create a 'special file' or directory that processes the data written to it in some way, or generates some arbitrary data when read from?

For example, a file which outputs the digits of pi when read from, or a file which uploads the data written to it to the cloud

Obviously, both of my ideas are quite useless, but I am really just interested in knowing whether it is possible.

Comment: [Almost a duplicate](https://superuser.com/q/1211877/432690). You ask not only about reading but this doesn't change much, I think.

Comment: With a suitable server on the other side and using `bash` (and possibly other shells) you could do the send to server by writing to `/dev/{tcp,udp}/<host>/<port>` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/399/redirection/21576/redirection-to-network-addresses) for example), though it doesn't really address your question directly

Comment: @EricRenouf Good point. "The other side" may be localhost as well.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski On the other hand, the OP there is asking about files that are interpreted when accessed, whilst I am asking about stream-like files where data is generated on the fly - the file is never fully generated

Comment: Over at U&L Giles has a [description](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60034/what-are-character-special-and-block-special-files-in-a-unix-system) of what happens when reading and writing files/block/character devices.  In essence, you'd have to have your own driver that the kernel can invoke when interacting with your "device" or you could possibly create one as a named pipe/FIFO and have a program on the other end doing what you wanted with it

Comment: In "user space", you can define a "named pipe" where your process is a the write (or read) end and a "client" is at the read (or write) one.

Comment: And besides writing your own kernel module for a device, and using a named pipe, another option is FUSE: Make a filesystem where you control reads and writes to *all* files in this filesystem.

Comment: It sounds like file system in user space see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace