# Dynamic or virtual file content, similar to /sys/*

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, fuse

Imagine you wanted a file - for example /etc/hosts - but every time the file was read, rather than reading it from the filesystem, its contents were the output of an application - for example a script that greps the config in apache's sites-enabled

I feel like this should be possible, for example kernel code generates pretty much everything in `/sys` and `/proc`, which I believe it mounts as virtual filesystems. Is there some kind of general-purpose userspace virtual filesystem overlay already that would allow me to delegate a script or binary as the output that should be shown whenever a file is read, or does this use-case just not come up very often?

(I imagine its misuse could slow a system down considerably, and there are probably better ways - in the above case, a cron task that ran every 10 mins would be preferable - but I'm curious whether it's something that's been encountered before and attempted)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux: Interpreted-on-read (ala php) for local files](https://superuser.com/questions/1211877/linux-interpreted-on-read-ala-php-for-local-files)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called [FUSE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). The kernel allows fully-featured filesystems to be implemented in userspace and you might have used some of them already: sshfs, curlftpfs, ntfs-3g, archivefs, wikipediafs...

The FUSE interface is a bit more low-level than you describe (the filesystem still has to individually handle opens, reads, writes...), but it has bindings for various languages from Python to [bash](https://github.com/zevweiss/booze/blob/master/README.md). Most of them have a "hello world" example which can be adapted to provide an external program's output as the data.

FUSE currently works on Linux, various BSDs, macOS, Solaris...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I figured FUSE might feature in some way, but I couldn't find anything that made this more friendly for my use case - booze and similar might be a good starting point. Thanks!