# "Upload" pipe as if it were a regular file

Tags: bash, unix, redirection, pipe, file-descriptors

Suppose I want to tar and compress a file for upload to Google Drive or something, but all without ever saving an intermediate tarball (e.g. because of a lack of disk space and/or the disk is read-only). Sounds easy with the help of named file descriptors and command substitution, right?

```bsh
exec {foo}< <(tar -c -z $SOME_DIRECTORY)
ln -L -s /dev/fd/${foo} ~/foo # "-L" may or may not be necessary here
```

Sadly, this doesn't seem to work. Upon attempting to upload this "file" to Google Drive (I have not tested this elsewhere), it complains that the file could not be found. So I went ahead and tried to see what was wrong.

```
$ ls -H -l /dev/fd # "-H" because "/dev/fd" itself is a symbolic link
lrwx------ 1 dlam dlam 64 Oct 16 12:53 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 dlam dlam 64 Oct 16 12:53 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 dlam dlam 64 Oct 16 12:53 10 -> pipe:[1334334] # In bold red
lrwx------ 1 dlam dlam 64 Oct 16 12:53 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 dlam dlam 64 Oct 16 12:53 3 -> /proc/16635/fd
```

Looks like file descriptor `10` (which is of course that of the process) is linked to some kind of pipe descriptor or handle rather than an actual pipe file (`ls` shows it in red, as if indicating a broken link). Using `-L` instead of `-H`, `ls` does dereference it correctly and report the right file type.

```
$ ls -L -l /dev/fd
total 0
crw--w---- 1 dlam tty  136, 0 Oct 16 12:58 0
crw--w---- 1 dlam tty  136, 0 Oct 16 12:58 1
prw------- 1 dlam dlam      0 Oct 16 12:52 10 # Correctly reported as a pipe
crw--w---- 1 dlam tty  136, 0 Oct 16 12:58 2
dr-x------ 2 dlam dlam      0 Oct 16 12:58 3
```

Attempting to `cat` it, whether directly or by symbolic link, does succeed, however, so it's certainly not missing or broken. My guess is that something is reading the file descriptor link literally and thus tries to find a file literally named `pipe:[1334334]`, which is possibly why even `ls` thought it was a broken link without the `-L` switch. Whatever the case, what can I do to get it to read it as if a regular file to upload to Google Drive or something?

**Update**

So I tried to use a named pipe using `mkfifo` instead.

```
mkfifo foo
tar -c -z $SOME_DIRECTORY > foo &
```

But this didn't quite work, either. Google Drive in this case complains about it being unreadable, but, again, `cat`'ing it works fine.

Comment: Related: [Interpreted-on-read (ala php) for local files](https://superuser.com/q/1211877/432690).

Comment: I was actually thinking of a FUSE-based solution, but I didn't know about ScriptFS. Thanks, I'll try that out!

Answer (score 0):

Update based on your comment below.

So ... it seems you want to do this.  Take a process, connect that process's `stdout` to Firefox, and have Firefox stream that as the file's content during its file upload process.  You're trying to use a pipe/fifo in place of the file.

I think this doesn't work because Firefox wants to know the size of the file so it can generate a `Content-Length:` header - this tells the receiving system how much data is coming.  It's possible for a server to be configured to simply receive data of an unknown size, but this is usually considered a security issue (easy to exhaust server resources with this) and probably not enabled on the server end.  So probably no way to make Firefox take a fifo instead of a file without patching it.

If you can get the upload URL and find out the upload page's needs insofar as cookies, etc., and it doesn't need Javascript, you probably can rig something with `curl` if the server end will take an HTTP POST without a `Content-Length:` header.

---

Anything that has a file descriptor is only reachable from local processes; whether a file, fifo, device node, etc.

You can create these on the filesystem, but what is physically actually written to the filesystem is in essence special codes that make the local operating system behave differently when read/written.  Trying to send the actual content of these "special files" to another system (especially one you don't own control) and expecting that system to behave just like yours will fail.

If you want to connect them to another system you have to use a local program that is locally connected to that file descriptor and then sends/receives data to the world using the TCP/IP stack, etc.

Comment: Well, that's a disappointment. I was hoping that Firefox would open the pipe for reading as if it were a regular file (probably in read-only mode) in uploading it to Google Drive or whatever service I happen to be using. Though I do not know what Firefox actually does to open a file for reading, I would assume that it would be some equivalent of `fopen` in read mode. Too bad files are not abstract as I would have liked them to be.

Comment: Also, my initial assumption that this would work is not because I assume that the "other system" would behave like mine (it obviously probably doesn't), but because I assumed that the file even being a pipe would be abstracted by whatever calls Firefox is using to read it in the first place. I haven't tested this myself, but pipes should be readable with the usual `fopen` function and probably its relatives, so I don't know what Firefox is doing to open it for uploading to Google Drive.

Comment: Updated based on your comments.

Comment: I'm guessing the likes of ScriptFS (mentioned in a comment to the question) probably wouldn't work because of that (your updated response). I'll still try for good measure, though, although I still wonder if there is still some other kind of workaround that does not use pipes and is not "buy more storage".